# How can we remove lines begins with certain number using AWK?

Tags: awk

I need to remove all record of $1 when the very first value ($3) of $1 is greater than 7. $1 and $3 are sorted.
Original content:

```
101 26 5
101 29 6
101 20 7
104 26 1
104 23 2
105 28 2
105 25 3
108 28 9    
108 27 10
```

Desired output:

```
    101 26 5
    101 29 6       
    101 20 7
    104 26 1
    104 23 2
    105 28 2
    105 25 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ID ($1)? Only the first value in the row or the whole row? Based on your desired output it seems that you want to remove the whole line, so the answer given by @Kusalananda is correct.

Comment: Considering your comment to Kusalananda's answer, your question does not reflect what you expect. And your example is not unambiguous enough. Please update your question.

Answer (score 2):

To filter out all lines of input that has a value in column 3 that is greater than or equal to 7:

```
$ awk '$3 < 7 { print }' <data.in >data.out
```

The Awk script `$3 < 7 { print }` does the `print`, which will output the whole record (line), whenever the condition `$3 < 7` ("the value in field (column) 3 is less than 7") is true.

With your data, this results in a `data.out` file containing

```
101 26 1
101 29 2
101 20 3
104 26 1
104 23 2
105 28 2
```

Comment: @Kusalananda- To clarify my question, I want to remove Id($1) records if the very first record ($3) of the id is greater than 7. the Data is sorted based on the Id.

Comment: @Alula Your use of "Id" and "record" is confusing. A "record" in Awk is by default a line of input. Could you please clarify your question (in the text of the question, not as a comment), and describe what you need in terms of "columns" or "fields" instead, please?

Comment: I suspect that he wants to remove any line that the third digit of first entry in each line (i.e 101 understood as $1 by awk and similar progs when using space as delimeter) is greater than 7. In reality i suspect he wants to keep lines beginning with 101 , 104, 105 but not 108 since third digit is 8 , thus greater than 7.